Command works in terminal but does not work when passed to a subprocess
the project I am working on is trying get black formatter to run on our precommit hook. The command works in terminal but doesn't work in the subprocess.
def run_black() -> None:
    """Runs black formatter."""
    cmd = ["git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=d", "|", "grep -E \\.py$", "|", "xargs", "black --skip-string-normalization"]
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True, text=True)

I purposefully made changes so that Black will formatter but nothing changes and the commit goes through. I also get no error message.I tested the command on my terminal and it does work.
The sys.executable is /usr/local/bin/python3 however my python environment is /home/dev/opensource/.direnv/python-3.9.20/bin

If you're using shell=True, then the command should just be a string.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/92395/494134

If you use shell=True and a list, run will join the components of the list into a single string to be passed as an argument  to sh -c (or whatever menchaism your platform uses for executing the string as a shell command). How that happens may not be what you expect. Either create a single pipeline argument, as John Gordon recommends, or execute each pipeline component as a separate subprocess, using subprocess.PIPE to join the standout output of one command to the standard input of the next.

BTW, the original shell command (and anything that continues to use xargs in the same way) is buggy when your repo has .py files with spaces in their names (or the names of the directories containing them). xargs has surprising corner cases that lead to bugs when not NUL-delimiting items and using -0, or newline-delimiting and using -d $'\n' (that's bash syntax, note; /bin/sh as used by shell=True doesn't support it)

For this kind of hard-coded pipeline, I would use three separate subprocesses instead of a shell pipeline.
cmd1 = ["git", "diff", "--cached", "--name-only", "--diff-filter=d"]
cmd2 = ["grep", "-E", ".py$"]
cmd3 = ["xargs", "black", "--skip-string-normalization"]

p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.run(cmd3, stdin=p2.stdout)

shell=True and list arguments don't work well together.

...well, they don't work well together if you don't know what they're doing. A list of arguments passed with shell=True is perfectly reasonable if the subsequent ones are intended to be $0, $1, etc. read by the code in the first list element; that avoids the security issues present if someone tries to substitute strings directly into their code.

BTW, might make sense to use -z on git diff and grep to allow -0 to be passed to xargs so filenames with spaces don't misbehave.

I'd skip the grep and xargs and do the same thing in Python:
import subprocess

files = [
    fn
    for fn in subprocess.check_output(
        ["git", "diff", "--cached", "--name-only", "--diff-filter=d"],
        encoding="utf-8",
    ).splitlines()
    if fn.endswith(".py")
]
# NB: this could fail if the command line ends up being very long
subprocess.check_call(["black", "--skip-string-normalization", *files])


The only reason not to do this is that it imposes a limit on the number of files that can match before you hit an OSError due to overrunning maximum command line length.

@CharlesDuffy Yes – that's noted in the comment. However, that's manageable with a bit of extra work (that would be the work xargs already does for you, of course).
